# mongoDB adding an ObjectId to array objects that don't have one

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that has a field which is an array of objects...
I want to ADD an ObjectId to each of these objects, so it is easier to manipulate the array - without looping every time.

How do I do this?

My collection looks like this

```
people: {
    name: "Bob",
    shirts: [
        {
            type: "Tshirt",
            size: "xl",
            color: "Red"
        },          
        {
            type: "Tshirt",
            size: "xl",
            color: "Blue"
        },
        {
            type: "Tshirt",
            size: "xl",
            color: "Black"
        }
    ]
```

I would like the shirts objects to look like this

```
     {
        _id: ObjectId('qwe098sdf786qwe098sdf786'),
        type: "Tshirt",
        size: "xl",
        color: "Black"
     }
```

I think I want something like this (shown here with a specific person to test):

```
db.people.update( // query 
    {        
        $and : [
            _id: ObjectId('5eeb44c6a042791d28a8641f'),
            {
                $or: [
                { 'shirts._id': { $eq:null } },
                { 'shirts._id':{ $exists:false } }
                ]
            }           
        ]
    },{ // update 
        $set: { 'shirts._id': new ObjectId() }
    },{ // options
        "multi" : true
    }
);
```

However this is what I get:

> ```
> Cannot create field '_id' in element
> ```

no other message - no error and nothing happens...This particular record has an array of 3 with 2 having an "_id:null" and the third having an ObjectId

When trying this:

```
$set: { 'shirts._id': new ObjectId() } try $set: { 'shirts.$[]._id': new ObjectId() }
```

It generates IDENTICAL ObjectsIDs for each array element, I would put an unique index on this however, the use case probably wont see more then 2-3 items in the array with edge cases hitting 5-6, which seems like an abuse of an index

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `forEach`:

```
db.people.find({ ... }).forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.shirts.forEach(function (shirt) {
      if (shirt._id == null) {
        shirt._id = new ObjectId();
      }
    });
    db.people.save(doc);
  });
```